# Flutter: What does secondaryAnimation do while navigating?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) => FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: child,
    ),
    //...
  ),
);
```

You can see `transitionsBuilder` 3rd parameter takes an `Animation` but I don't understand its use. Can anyone explain that.

Docs aren't very clear.

Comment: its a disappear animation - contrary to the "main" one: *"The animation for the route being pushed on top of this route. This animation lets this route coordinate with the entrance and exit transition of route pushed on top of this route."*

Comment: Thanks but again docs are bit confusing to me (maybe I am not that good in flutter yet), can you please tell me when will it be used or something more on it?

Comment: https://medium.com/@agungsurya/create-custom-router-transition-in-flutter-using-pageroutebuilder-73a1a9c4a171

Comment: a shorter version: animation is a value which is changing while an animation is running. Here it will most likely go from 1 to 0 in a defined time range in a defined curve. So it basically fades out in terms of opacity.

Comment: see [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/buildTransitions.html) and find the paragraph starting with: `When the Navigator pushes a route on the top of its stack, the secondaryAnimation can be used to define how the route that was on the top of the stack leaves the screen`

Comment: @Marc Sorry but that's not the case here, the secondaryAnimation value stays `0` throughout transition.

Comment: @pskink Thanks now it made some sense, I'll be happy to accept and upvote your answer if you can write the same sentence by quoting. You've been very helpful.

Comment: i am glad it helped, your welcome to write a self answer now ...

Comment: yes, you are right: I'm very lazy :-)

Answer (score 1):

All thanks to my friend [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)

> When the Navigator pushes a route on the top of its stack, the secondaryAnimation can be used to define how the route that was on the top of the stack leaves the screen. Similarly when the topmost route is popped, the secondaryAnimation can be used to define how the route below it reappears on the screen. When the Navigator pushes a new route on the top of its stack, the old topmost route's secondaryAnimation runs from 0.0 to 1.0. When the Navigator pops the topmost route, the secondaryAnimation for the route below it runs from 1.0 to 0.0.